# SVM testing - normalization of test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm working with SVM model to classify 5 different classes. (N1, N2, N3, W, R)
Feature extractions -> Data normalization -> train SVM
when I tested the model (20%, 80% usual train-test-split), it shows high accuracy [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0OVw.png)

But when I tried testing with a completely new dataset, with the same method of
Feature extractions -> Data normalization -> test on trained SVM model
It came out really badly.

**Let's say the original dataset used in training is A, and the new test dataset is B.
when I trained the model only with A and tested B, it came out really badly.**

First I thought it was model overfitting so I included A and B to train the model and tested with B. It came out badly again...

I think the problem is the normaliztion process.  It eventually worked when I tried new dataset **C**, but this time I brought the train A data, concatenated A+C to normalize, and then cut only C dataset out from it. And when I compared that with the data C normalized alone, it was different..

I used MinMaxScaler from sklearn.
I mean mathematically speaking of course it's different.. because every dataset has different minimum maximum value and normalized data will be different when mixed with other data.

My question is, when you test with new dataset, is it normal to bring the train dataset to normalize it together and then take out the test datapart only?? It's like mixing A(112x12), B(15x12) -> normalize (127x12) together -> take out (15x12)

Or should I start from fixing the code from feature extraction and training SVM?

(I attached the code, and each feature has  12x1 shape which means each stage has 12xN matrix.)

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

# Load training data
N1_train = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Train_N1_features")
N2_train = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Train_N2_features")
N3_train = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Train_N3_features")
W_train = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Train_W_features")
R_train = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Train_R_features")

# Load test data
N1_test = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Test_N1_features")
N2_test = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Test_N2_features")
N3_test = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Test_N3_features")
W_test = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Test_W_features")
R_test = pd.read_pickle("C:/Users/User/Desktop/EWHADATASETS/Features/Test_R_features")

# normalize with original raw features and take only test out
N1_scaled_test = features.normalize_together(N1_test, N1_train, "N1")
N2_scaled_test = features.normalize_together(N2_test, N2_train, "N2")
N3_scaled_test = features.normalize_together(N3_test, N3_train, "N3")
W_scaled_test = features.normalize_together(W_test, W_train, "W")
R_scaled_test = features.normalize_together(R_test, R_train, "R")

def normalize_together(test, raw, stage_no):
    together = pd.concat([test, raw], ignore_index=True)
    scaled_test = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(together.iloc[:, :-1]))
    scaled_test['label'] = "{}".format(stage_no)
    scaled_test = scaled_test.iloc[0:test.shape[0], :]

    return scaled_test
```

Comment: scikit-learn is already taking care of this, by providing separate `fit` (for training data) and `transform` for (test & unseen data) methods, as explained in several places (e.g. [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/whats-the-difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models)) - https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

Test data should remain unseen during training (includes preprocessing) - don't use both test + train data to compute a common normalisation factor. Normalise the training set. Separately, normalise the test set.

Why? It's vital to use an **unseen** test partition to evaluate your trained model. Otherwise you have not tested the ability for your model to generalise - imagine playing a game of cards where you have already have prior knowledge of the cards or order of the deck.